# Fetch child's lookup field data

Tags: soql

I need to take out data of an object (Object_C__c) in a single query. We have another object (Object_B__c) which has a lookup relationship with Object_A__c and Object_C__c. My requirement is I need to take out Object C's data on a single query made on Object A. Is there a way to fetch data in a reverse order i.e I know we can easily take out 3 level data Object_B__r.Object_C__r.Name, but we need the same info by making the query on Object_A__c. Please suggest if this is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You cant Achieve it through single Query.

**Consider you are in ObjA Level.**

***Modulue:***

> In your case ObjA is parent and ObJB is child

AND

> Objc is parent and objB is child.

You cant fetch data in single query,

1.You can write relationship query on ObjA

2.Using that relationship query collect  ObjB ids from ObjA

3.Using ObjBids make query on ObjC

Surely collections will play a major role.

If you are in ObjB level, You can easily get ObjA and ObjC data

***Note:***

> Parent to child ->its One Level
>
> child to parent-> you traverse upto 5 level.

Answer (score 0):

let's call the following objects:

Object A = Account

Object B = Opportunities

Object c = Contacts

we could do the following:

map> contactToOpportuntiesMap = new map>();
List contacts = new list();

```
For(Account acc : [select id, (select id, account.name from contacts), (select id from Opportunities) from account]){
    for(Contact con : acc.Contacts){
        contactToOpportuntiesMap.put(con.Id,acc.Opportunities);
        contacts.add(con);
    }
}
```

do all you want the contacts and all the data u need:

```
for(Contact con : contacts){
    Account acc = con.Account;
    list<Opportunity> OppsRelatedToContact = contactToOpportuntiesMap.containsKey(con.Id) ? contactToOpportuntiesMap.get(con.Id) : new list<Opportunity>();

    //do your thing here with all the date related to the contact
}
```

if you need to limit the contacts you process add a where clause

```
set<Id> contactIds = new set<Id>();

For(Account acc : [select id, (select id, account.name from contacts where id in: contactIds), (select id from Opportunities) from account]){
    for(Contact con : acc.Contacts){
        contactToOpportuntiesMap.put(con.Id,acc.Opportunities);
        contacts.add(con);
    }
}
```